# How to fix a kivy button that appears transparent by default

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I am experiencing weird behavior with kivy == 1.11. My Buttons appear transparent even though I specifically give them full opacity.My code is as follows:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Names(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,tb = {}, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        names = ["Jane","Joe","John","Janet"]
        table = GridLayout(cols=columns,padding=30,spacing=.5,size_hint_y=None)
        table.bind(minimum_height=table.setter('height'))
        floor = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height-180),bar_color=(0.06,.47,.47, 1),bar_inactive_color=(.06,.47,.47, 1),bar_width=10,scroll_type=['bars'])
        floor.add_widget(table)
        self.add_widget(floor)

        for h in names:
            btn = Button(text=h,color=(1,0,0,1), disabled=True)
            btn.background_color=(.06, .45, .45, 1)
            btn.background_disabled=''
            table.add_widget(btn)

class SAPP(App):
    def build(self):
        return Names()

if __name__=='__main__':
    SAPP().run(
```

Anyone have a similar issue?or a solution?

Comment: The `background_color` may be your problem. According to the [documenttion](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_color), the `background_color` `acts as a multiplier to the texture colour`. Try eliminating the `background_color` and see the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with Kivy itself,I was using the github Kivy-1.11-dev release which, needless to say, is still under development. Rolling back to Kivy-1.10, the currently stable build fixed my problem.I also tested this with other programs and seemed to be the same problem/fix

Answer (score 0):

I think the default disabled button image, which you have not changed, is semitransparent. Did you mean to set `btn.background_disabled_normal`?